# How do I print 4 documents on one sheet with text in landscape orientation?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I want to print my document in the below format (4 pages in a sheet, with text written vertically) in Microsoft Word:

[image: Expected result]

I tried with the options in printing form of Microsoft Word, but it prints my document like this (with ratio scale 0.5):

[image: Actual result]

What is the solution?

Comment: Is your page format portrait? Change it to landscape.

Comment: That is landscape.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution [hear](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/printing-multiple-pages-per-sheet-in-landscape-in/7a6576cc-93ed-40e9-8b8d-a2112ea40f3e?auth=1), seems which works:

> Go to File > Print (leave settings as default) and click on Printer Properties > Finishing tab > select 4 Pages Per Sheet > select Landscape orientation – print comes out as four separate pages, one print per page. It seems that Word 2010 overrides anything set in Printer Properties